# Print values from a foreach by range?

Tags: php, printing, foreach, range

I have a array of various strings:

```
$arreglo = array('juan castillo','andres felipe','gerardo diaz','onofre perez','paolo jara','jason guerra','luis lopez','ivan delgado','diego teran','andres figueroa','ines mosquera','karen chamorro','marco fernandez','rene valencia','valeria ramirez','ximena villavicencio','danilo zambrano','amanda yela','pablo morillo','william rodriguez','carlos chavez','camilo castro');
foreach ($arreglo as $key => $value) {
      echo $value;
}
```

How i can print only a range of specific strings for example a range of values from 'andres figueroa' to 'danilo zambrano'. Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways, but a simple `for` will do the trick:

```
for ( $i = 9; $i <= 16; $i++ )
    echo $arreglo[$i];
```

Of course you probably don't want to hardcode the indices like that, and you
can use `array_search` to find them:

```
$start = array_search( 'andres figueroa', $arreglo );
$stop = array_search( 'danilo zambrano', $arreglo );


for ( $i = $start; $i <= $stop; $i++ )
    echo $arreglo[$i];
```

Note that this will only work if `andres figureoa` comes before `danilo zambrano` in the array! To sort them you could do:

```
list( $start, $stop ) = array( min($start, $stop), max( $start, $stop ) );
```

You can also use `range()`:

```
foreach ( range( $start, $stop ) as $i )
    echo $arreglo[$i];
```

Comment: can i specify the range with a string?

Answer (score 0):

This will only work if the array is always 0 indexed, but you can use [`array_search`](http://php.net/array-search) to find the index for the start/end elements you're seeking (assuming you're always seeking them out by value value) and then use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array-slice) to only iterate over the values within the range you want...

```
$arreglo = [
            'juan castillo',
            'andres felipe',
            'gerardo diaz',
            'onofre perez',
            'paolo jara',
            'jason guerra',
            'luis lopez',
            'ivan delgado',
            'diego teran',
            'andres figueroa',
            'ines mosquera',
            'karen chamorro',
            'marco fernandez',
            'rene valencia',
            'valeria ramirez',
            'ximena villavicencio',
            'danilo zambrano',
            'amanda yela',
            'pablo morillo',
            'william rodriguez',
            'carlos chavez',
            'camilo castro'
           ];
$startPos = array_search('andres figueroa', $arreglo, true);
$endPos   = array_search('danilo zambrano', $arreglo, true);

foreach (array_slice($arreglo, $startPos, $startPos - $endPos + 2) as $key => $value) {
      echo $value, "\n";
}
```

Keep in mind this will be an inclusive range so that includes `'andres figueroa'` and `'danilo zambrano'` as well as everything in between. You can also run the array through [`array_values`](http://php.net/array-values) if you aren't sure that it's zero-indexed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arreglo = array('juan castillo','andres felipe','gerardo diaz','onofre perez','paolo jara','jason guerra','luis lopez','ivan delgado','diego teran','andres figueroa','ines mosquera','karen chamorro','marco fernandez','rene valencia','valeria ramirez','ximena villavicencio','danilo zambrano','amanda yela','pablo morillo','william rodriguez','carlos chavez','camilo castro');

$from = array_search("andres figueroa", $arreglo);
$to   = array_search("danilo zambrano", $arreglo);

print_r(array_slice($arreglo, $from, ($to - $from)+1));
```

Answer (score -1):

How do you plan to pass the start and end points? Strings?

Edit:

Use array_search to find the positions of the strings in the array then do a for loop.